# Before class & after class not working with Selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing functional test cases using Selenium+Cucumber

I would like to place the following code in BeforeClass

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<somepath>\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I tried to place the Before class both in Super class and in same class as well. But it doesnt get fired. What is the reason ?

1. BeforeClass in super class

   ```
   public class Super_Steps {
       @BeforeClass    
       public static void beforeClass() {
           System.out.println("Before class");
       }
   ..
   }

   public class Login_Steps extends Super_Steps  {
   ..
   ```
2. BeforeClass in same class

   ```
   public class Login_Steps {
       @BeforeClass
       public static void beforeClass() {
           System.out.println("Before class");
       }
   ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you have any method annotated with @Test ?? without that how can you execute this !!

Comment: yes, I do have @Test and it is getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction for using @BeforeClass in superclasses. According to the [JUnit api](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html): "The @BeforeClass methods of superclasses will be run before those the current class." Possibly double check if you have imported in the superclass junit.BeforeClass:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
```

Comment: Any more solutions ?

Comment: Could you please provide any more details? The case seems to be pretty straightforward and the reason for this behavior should be somewhere in implementation details. Also some logs will be of help for troubleshooting.

Comment: What details should I provide ?